# Grabbing all regex matches of "$#" from a string

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have a string that contains multiple instances of a dollar sign followed by a positive number. I need to grab each instance out using regex.

Here's an example of a string:

```
"This that $1 who $2"
```

Here's what I have so far using vb.net:

```
Dim wordSplitMatches As Match = Regex.Match("This that $1 who $2", "(\$\d+)+")
```

This works great for grabbing the $1 but how do I set it up so that I get multiple groups with all the matches in?

This is the output at the moment:

```
? wordsplitmatches.groups(1).value
"$1"
? wordsplitmatches.groups(2).value
""
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex.Match only returns the first match.

Use [Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx) to return all matches.

Comment: Knew it would be simple. Thanks alot.